# Search for a file in my channel with Telegram Bot C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Suppose I have a telegram bot that is Admin of a channel. Is there any way I can search for a music file with its name?

Comment: A Telegram bot is not allowed to search on group. Its not possible.

Answer (score 2):

[You can't search on your group with Telegram bot, but you can revise and save file from group and then search on your database. A Telegram bot is not allowed to search on group. Its not possible.](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

October 11, 2017
Bot API 3.4.

- Bots can now send and receive Live Locations. Added new field
  live_period to the sendLocation method and the
  editMessageLiveLocation and stopMessageLiveLocation methods as well
  as the necessary objects for inline bots. Bots can use the new
  setChatStickerSet and deleteChatStickerSet methods to manage group
  sticker sets. The getChat request now returns the group's sticker set
  for supergroups if available. Bots now receive entities from media
  captions in the new field caption_entities in Message.

August 23, 2017
Bot API 3.3.

- Bots can now mention users via inline mentions, without using
  usernames. getChat now also returns pinned messages in supergroups,
  if present. Added the new field pinned_message to the Chat object.
  Added the new fields author_signature and forward_signature to the
  Message object. Added the new field is_bot to the User object.

July 21, 2017

- Bot API 3.2. Teach your bot to handle stickers and sticker sets.
- Added new methods for working with stickers: getStickerSet,
  uploadStickerFile, createNewStickerSet, addStickerToSet,
  setStickerPositionInSet, and deleteStickerFromSet. Added the fields
  set_name and mask_position to the Sticker object, plus two new
  objects, StickerSet, and MaskPosition.

June 30, 2017
Bot API 3.1. Build your own robotic police force for supergoups with these new methods for admin bots:

- Added new methods restrictChatMember and promoteChatMember to manage
  users and admins, added new parameter until_date to kickChatMember
  for temporary bans. Added new methods exportChatInviteLink,
  setChatPhoto, deleteChatPhoto, setChatTitle, setChatDescription,
  pinChatMessage and unpinChatMessage to manage groups and channels.
  Added the new fields photo, description and invite_link to the Chat
  object. Added the new fields until_date, can_be_edited,
  can_change_info, can_post_messages, can_edit_messages,
  can_delete_messages, can_invite_users, can_restrict_members,
  can_pin_messages, can_promote_members, can_send_messages,
  can_send_media_messages, can_send_other_messages and
  can_add_web_page_previews to

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can do this by bot now, but you can suggest it to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport). :(

You can think about Telegram dorsn't let you get message list, even single message, so you need to log all useful updates to your own database .